# CoreBluetooth unsupported

Tags: swift, xcode, bluetooth, ios-simulator, core-bluetooth

I try to operate CoreBluetooth on my IOS Simulator but it say me that is unsupported, so i've been looking for on the web and apparently everyone said that CoreBluetooth works only on physical phone.
Are there any ways to operate Bluetooth on the IOS simulator?
if yes, which one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are, mostly, correct. CoreBlutooth does not work in the Simulator. Since macOS 10.10, you can write CoreBluetooth code for Mac. You can use that to do some testing on Mac (by writing a Mac app that shares the same CoreBluetooth code), but that does not allow it to work in the Simulator.

Comment: Great idea, i'm going to write an mac app wich  communicate with my iphone app, thank you a lot!!